# Flask - User input and Buttons with back-end actions, returning text to user

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a small Flask test and attempting to do the following:

I have two forms.

The first - receives users input, then has a submit button. When the submit button is pressed I would like to 1.) execute a back-end Python program using the two values from 'doritos' and 'oreos' then 2.) return some relative text back to the user (i.e., successful) on the same page, next to the button or in some text window.

Question - How can I pass the values received from this form back to foo?

Question - How can I return a text value back to the user?

The second - basic buttons which call a Python program and return and return some relative text back to the user (i.e., successful). I'm assuming I can use the above questions to answer this as well.

Documentation I continue to see online uses app.route and routes the user to another page with results. I want to keep the user on the same page and just return text. If this is too vague you can tell me to RTFM. Just having a hard time figuring this out.

See below for my code:

**index.html:**

```
<form action="/foo" method="post">
CHIPS:<br>
<input type="text" name="doritos"><br>
SNACKS:<br>
<input type="text" name="oreos"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="/coo" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="pita" value="pita"><br>
<input type="submit" name="chip" value="chip"<br>
</form>
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", title='Home')

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    try:
        ..receive user-input values..
        ..do some back end actions..
        return 'Successful.'
    except:
        return 'Failed.'

@app.route('/coo')
def coo():
    try: 
        if request.form['pita']:
            ..do some back end actions..
            return 'Successful.'
        elif request.form['chip']:
            ..do some back end actions..
            return 'Successful.'
    except:
        return 'Failed.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask has the [Jinja2](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/) built in (you're already using it in the form of `render_template`), so one simple solution to this problem could be to create a template with your forms, and pass a "success" or "fail" message to the template when data is posted.

Consider the following `index.html` template snippet:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    CHIPS:<br />
    <input type="text" name="doritos"><br />
    SNACKS:<br />
    <input type="text" name="oreos"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{% if fooResponse is not none %}
    {{ fooResponse }}
{% endif %}

<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="pita" value="pita"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="chip" value="chip"><br />
</form>
{% if cooResponse is not none %}
    {{ cooResponse }}
{% endif %}
```

Your Python might then look something like this (assuming you don't want to navigate away from `/`/`/index`, and based on your question I'm assuming that the output shown from each form is non-persistent and mutually exclusive):

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")

    if request.form["submit"] == "submit":
        doritos = request.form["doritos"]
        oreos = request.form["oreos"]
        success = process(doritos, oreos)

        return render_template("index.html", fooResponse="Successful" if success else "Failed")

     elif request.form["submit"] == "pita":
        success = process("pita")
        return render_template("index.html", cooResponse="Successful" if success else "Failed")

     elif request.form["submit"] == "chip":
        success = process("chip")
        return render_template("index.html", cooResponse="Successful" if success else "Failed")
```

Comment: Unless I put `return render_template("index.html")` directly after `def index():` I'm unable to load index.html and I get the error message "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.". However, if I place `return render_template("index.html") directly after `def index():` the site comes up, however, when I click a button I get the error message "Method Not Allowed". Also the above index.html creates three buttons (pita,chip,submit2)? I'm just looking for pita or chip to perform some action? Can you clarify on what the "process" function does and how to import

Comment: Modified. `process` is just a placeholder for whatever you want to do with the posted data. It should return `True` or `False`, which can then be used to return "Successful"/"Failed"

Answer (score 1):

You can link your form submission to an ajax call in javascript. The ajax function would send the data to an api, python would do all calculations and send a response. The ajax function receives that response in the front end and displays whatever text/data you want in the frontend.

Consider something like:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/oreos-and-doritos",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data-from-form),
        success: function (data) {
            // do whatever changes are needed in the frontend,
            // like displaying a message
            $('#msg').text(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            // do some error handling here
        }
    }));
```